# Finding the distinct roots of a fractional complex number

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

If I have to find the roots of the equation $$\Bigl(\frac{1-w}{1+w}\Bigr)^4 = 1, \text{where} \hspace{5pt}  w \in \mathbb{C},$$  then I can simply let the term $$\frac{1-w}{1+w} = s. $$  Therefore $$s^4 = 1,$$ which means by inspection that $$s = i, -i, 1, -1.$$ But if I would like to use the formula $$w= re^{i\theta}$$ and/or $$w= r^{\frac{1}{n}}\biggl(\cos\biggl(\frac{\theta}{n} +\frac{2k \pi}{n}\biggr) + i \sin\biggl(\frac{\theta}{n} +\frac{2k \pi}{n}\biggr)\biggr)$$ to solve for these roots, how would I go about doing so? I know that $n = 4$, so for the four distinct roots, $k = 0, 1, 2 ,3$. After this, I  don't know how to proceed.

Comment: You could consider $4$ cases. First assume $s=1$. Then obviously $w=0$. For $s=-1$ we obtain $1-w=-1-w$, a contradiction. For $s=i$, well, now it's up to you.

Comment: I know that there are 4 cases, but to use the second formula for w, I have to put the first complex number equation into polar form

Comment: I see. Then just delete the first part (which we have solved anyway) and only ask about $w=re^{i\theta}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you expect a benefit of expressing $w$ in polar form (and as a fourth root), but nothing substantiates this. On the opposite, I guess that it will completely obscure the resolution.

You can of course solve

$$s^4=1$$ in polar form, with

$$r^4e^{4i\theta}=1=e^{i2n\pi},$$

giving

$$s=e^{in\pi/2}$$ or $$s=1,i,-1,-i$$ but you already know this.

---

A better option is to rewrite as

$$w^4-4w^3+6w^2-4w+1=w^4+4w^3+6w^2+4w+1$$ which simplifies as

$$w^3+w=0$$ or $w=0,w=\pm i$.

Comment: Wouldn't 1 and -1 be roots of this equation too?

Comment: @Shrek.Spongebob: stop confusing $w$ and $s$.

Comment: So essentially if we solve $$\frac{1-w}{1+w}$$ for each value of s by equating the fraction to each value of s, we can obtain the distinct roots? Then this wouldn't require the formula involving theta right?

Comment: @Shrek.Spongebob: this is precisely the method in your post and in Aqua's.

Comment: @Shrek.Spongebob: I am afraid that you still don't understand that $w$ must not be set in polar form. You confuse $w$ and $s$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this please?

Comment: @Shrek.Spongebob: write $w$ in polar form and solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So you have $${1-w\over 1+w} = s$$
for $s\in \{1,-1,i,-i\}$. Now solving this on $w$ we get $$w={1-s\over 1+s}$$

So:

if $s=1$ you get $w=0$

if $s=-1$ then $w$ does not exists

if $s=i$ then $w = {(1-i)^2\over 2} = -i$

and

if $s=-i$ you get $w=i$.

Comment: That's exactly what the OP doesn't want, see the comments.